# Should question titles actually be questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I see a lot of questions with what I would consider bad titles. [Couple](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/567/tortoise-makes-peeping-or-whistling-sound-while-breathing) [examples](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/170/substrate-for-a-redfoot-tortoise).

Shouldn't titles be actual questions and give you an understanding of what the question is about instead of broad statements?

Answer (score 7):

I like the **[elevator pitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_pitch)** approach

> An elevator pitch, elevator speech, or elevator statement is a short
>   summary used to quickly and simply define a person, profession,
>   product, service, organization or event and its value proposition.
>
> The name "elevator pitch" reflects the idea that it should be possible
>   to deliver the summary in the time span of an elevator ride, or
>   approximately thirty seconds to two minutes.

Your title should very briefly describe what the question is, so that without entering it, an answerer would know what its about, and whether or not he can actually help.

I like to make my titles questions. Because questions attract people's eyes. This is a Q&A site after all :)

Answer (score 4):

I think it is important and I think that we should make an effort to edit question titles in self contained questions - there is no way around it - Q&A is the name of the game here.

We can take a lot from the [previously linked post by psubsee2003](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title), in particular the good/bad examples given. Simply appending "How do I.." to a posts title doesn't make it better. It reminds me of [Smurf Naming Convention](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html). The title should be brief and should try to catch the attention of readers. Short and sweet.

These titles will appear on the homepage, so we really need to make them great!

I'm sure there will be some exceptions but I believe we should strive to maintain the Q&A essence that the network is built on.

Answer (score -1):

I don't necessarily think so.  The title is not the question.  The title is a brief introduction to the question/problem described in the post body, but it doesn't necessarily mean it needs to be a question.

In fact, this [MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/182513) answer seems to discourage this to some extent.  So I think the answer to your question is no.